# System Generator: How to make an implementation a mathematical function through a ROM

Tags: fpga, xilinx, rom, xilinx-system-generator, matlab

I want to put in a ROM a vector of values I have in the workspace. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you to all possible references, articles or comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ROM block (from the memory section of the Xilinx blockset).

It has a parameter called `Inital value vector` - put the name of the vector in there.  Put `length(vector_name)` in the `depth` parameter.

Setup the `output type` tab to the fixed point representation you want to use.  Bear in mind the sizes of RAM bclock you have available in the target FPGA when selecting the `number of bits`. For example, 2k elements of 9 bits fits just as well in a single RAM block as 2k elements of 8 bits (in case you, or other readers, aren't already aware of that).

Job done!

Comment: It has been so easy that is difficult to believe.